# DateTime format not formatting correctly

Tags: date, format

I have a datetime format in XML and I'm trying to unmarshall the values as follows:

```
2013-03-17T19:12:14Z -> 2013-03-17 19:12 +0100
```

I have used Joda's `DateTime` and a `DateTimeAdapter` class to override the unmarshalling. The datetime format is coming out weird, as follows:

```
{"iMillis":1363510800000,"iChronology":{"iBase":{"iBase":{"iBase":
{"iMinDaysInFirstWeek":4}},"iParam":{"iZone":{"iTransitions":    
[-9223372036854775808,-3852662325000,-1691964000000,-1680472800000,
-1664143200000,-1650146    400000,-1633903200000,-1617487200000,
-1601848800000,- etc etc.
```

Can anyone help me format this date?

Answer (score 0):

I was unable to figure out the answer so I've tried the following:

```
    SimpleDateFormat sd = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm Z");
    DateTime dateTime = new DateTime(v);
    long dateTimeMiliSec = dateTime.getMillis();
    Date date = new Date(dateTimeMiliSec);

    return sd.format(date);
```

So 2013-03-17T09:00:00Z converts to 2013-03-17 09:00 +0000